# Drag and select text in HTML5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am working on a word search game. I needed to know how can I select and store the text using mouse on a canvas to compare with the stored set of words. Does canvas provide the drag and select functionality?Please help! Or if there is some other way like easeljs.

I am searching for drag and select something like http://wordsearch.randomsaladgames.com/

Comment: You can't. Text drawn to canvas becomes pixels and cease to exist as text the moment it is rendered. You will have to implement all logic yourselves to simulate text as an object etc. - or use a library that already does it for you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate which type of library??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Epistemex says, canvas does not "remember" where you drew the text on the canvas so it can't locate or drag that text.

You would have to implement the logic to "remember" the text yourself using javascript.

If you want to implement the logic then here's an outline of the tools you'll need.

- create an object that holds your text's characteristics (x,y,width,height,textContent)
- create a function that clears the canvas and redraws the text at a new x,y position
- listen for mouse events and reposition the text based on how far the user has dragged the mouse

Canvas libraries have done the implementation work for you.

Here's an example using KineticJS:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WxGrQ/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x:100,
        y:100,
        text:"Drag this Text",
        fontSize:18,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: .5,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(text);
    layer.draw();


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Grab the text and drag it.</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I dont want to drag the text, I want the mouse to be dragged over it and select it if it user has selected the right word against a set of saved words. How can that be done ?? :(

Comment: I see...Similar to DOM events, KineticJS text can trigger mouseenter and mouseleave events when the user drags the mouse over the text. Here is a KineticJS example that detects if the mouse is hovering over the text:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/S6qQZ/  I leave it to you to implement your game logic.  Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/6gnTm/1/

It's draggable.

Kinetic JS can at least let you 'drag' text as a separate object, like I think you are looking for. The demo has some other functionality that is probably not what you need, but this is a demo I made for another purpose, just reusing it here.

```
    var textGroup = new Kinetic.Group({ // I put everything in groups, and groups can be draggable, so can text nodes.
        x: 200,
        y: 30,
        draggable: true
    });

   // create the text path with text on it
    var textpath = new Kinetic.TextPath({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        id: 'textpath1',
        align: 'center',
        fill: '#333',
        fontSize: '48',
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        text: typedText,
        data: SVGdataString
    });

    textGroup.add(textpath);
```